# Simple Redux form using react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

In the execution of the below code snippet I'm getting the following error.
Error: Field must be inside a component decorated with reduxForm()

src/components/LoginForm/index.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form';

class LoginForm extends Component {
    render () {
        const {handleSubmit} = this.props;
        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Field 
                    name="username"
                    component="input"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Username"
                />

                <Field 
                    name="password"
                    component="input"
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Password"
                />
                <button type="submit" label="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>    
        );
    }
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'simpleform'
})(LoginForm)
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the Field in ```reduxForm``` instead of just plain ```form```?

Comment: Are there any modifications to be done for the above code?

Comment: I guess it should be wrapped within ReduxForm component (as the error says)

Comment: Isn't this the way to do so?                                                                                                export default reduxForm({
    form: 'simpleform'
})(LoginForm)

Comment: Error: Field must be inside a component decorated with reduxForm()                           The following error comes for the following code snippet..src/index.js                      ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
    </Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
    );

Answer (score 0):

Try this and also it is class component not a functional component so how you imported your LoginForm in the App.js

Import like this

```
import LoginForm from 'LoginForm'; // Default export
```

and export like this:

```
LoginForm= reduxForm({
       form: 'simpleform'
    })(LoginForm)
    export default LoginForm;
```

Comment: can you update the post by sharing the App.js as well

Answer (score 0):

Making your class component to a functional component may be the solution. Just try this out.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";

const LoginForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field
        name="username"
        component="input"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Username"
      />
      <Field
        name="password"
        component="input"
        type="password"
        placeholder="Password"
      />
      <button type="submit" label="submit">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: "simpleform"
})(LoginForm);
```